# Adding image from resources - Visual Studio 11 Beta C#

Tags: c#, image, resources

I'd like to add an image to my C# WinForm app in Visual Studio 11 Beta. I therefore added my png in the resources tab/images with "add resource" + "from existing file..." (that worked fine and it is listed in the tab).

Now i tried to access it with:
`Bitmap Image = new Bitmap(MyProject.Properties.Resources.MyImage);` but it doesn't find anything in "Resources". (The only options i get for Resources is: Culture, Equals, ReferenceEquals and ResourceManager)
I also tried to set the build action of the image to embedded resource in the properties tab

Adding the png with its local path works like a charm.

Am I doing it wrong or is there another problem?
(Im working with .NET Framework 4)

Comment: still works on my machine...don't think that this is the problem cause everything else works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to load it out of the assembly (build action = embedded resource), you'll need to read the `Stream` from the assembly like so:

```
using System.Reflection;
//...
var image = new Bitmap(
    Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().
        GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Properties.Resources.MyImage.png"));
```

This assumes that your file is located in `/Properties/Resources/MyImage.png` and that your assembly's root namespace is `MyProject`.